# How to link gpg key to launchpad

Tags: ubuntu, launchpad, gpg-signature

I have followed the link 
https://askubuntu.com/questions/100281/how-do-i-make-a-pgp-key to generate my gpg key now i want to add key to my launchpad.

I got a mail from launchpad upon adding my key fingerprint and the mail shows something like this [image: GPG MAIL to my GMAIL-ID]

How to confirm the key and add it to my launchpad..???

any suggestion or way forward would be off great help..

Any help??

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Everything is the same just copy the contents right from 
`---BEGIN PGP MESSAGE---` TO `END PGP MESSAGE`and paste to a file say `xyz.txt`
and then decrypt using `gpg -d <xyz.txt>`  and you will be redirected to a token link `launchpad link` and then keys are added to your `launchpad`.